# How to position qtrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, qtree

Suppose, I have 2 qtrees, that I want to put below each other:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.{1}
    [.1-1 ]
    [.\node (1) {1-2}; ]
]
\node [below = 0.5cm of 1.south] (note-1) {la la la};
\draw[-]
      (note-1.north) -- (1.south);
\Tree
[.{2}
    [.2-1 ]
    [.2-2 ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now trees overlap. The 1-st has a comment 'la la la', residing in a separate node. If I didn't have it, I could put both trees into nodes and position nodes. But how to position bare qtrees? So their roots would match horizontally and the 2-nd tree would be below 'la la la'.

Comment: Can you put the two trees in two different `tikzpicture` environments, and add a line break between them? For example, `\begin{tikzpicture} <codes for 1st tree> \end{tikzpicture} \\ \begin{tikzpicture} <codes for 2nd tree> \end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides just using two different TikZ pictures that are separated by `\\`, you can use the manual added node `note-1` to shift the whole second tree down.

You can also use an already defined node of the Tree but you need to re-establish its coordinates by the help of an auxiliary coordinate (Code 2):

```
% somewhere in the tree:
          [. \node (lowest node) {1-2-2-1-1};  ]

% outside of tree:
\coordinate (aux1) at (lowest node);

% The coordinate aux1 can now be used for placement, e.g.
% below=of toptree |- aux1
```

The `|-` makes sure that the `2` is placed under the `1`.

### Code 1

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.\node (toptree) {1};
    [.1-1 ]
    [.\node (1) {1-2}; ]
]
\node [below = 0.5cm of 1.south] (note-1) {la la la};
\draw[-] (note-1.north) -- (1.south);

\begin{scope}[every tree node/.append style={below=of toptree |- note-1.south}]
\Tree
[.2
    [.2-1 ]
    [.2-2 ]
]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code 2

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.\node (toptree) {1};
    [.1-1 ]
    [.1-2 
      [.1-2-1 
        [.1-2-2-1 
          [. \node (lowest node) {1-2-2-1-1};  ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
]
\coordinate (aux1) at (lowest node);

\begin{scope}[opacity=.5,every tree node/.append style={below=of toptree |- lowest node}]
\Tree
[.2
    [.2-1 ]
    [.2-2 ]
]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every tree node/.append style={below=of toptree |- aux1}]
\Tree
[.2
    [.2-1 ]
    [.2-2 ]
]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image] [image]

Comment: The `toptree` node isn't even needed as `lowest node` refers in `below=of lowest node |- aux1` to the first node in the tree.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `scope` with an appropriate shifting for the second tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.1
    [.1-1 ]
    [.\node (1) {1-2}; ]
]
\node [below = 0.5cm of 1.south] (note-1) {la la la};
\draw[-]
      (note-1.north) -- (1.south);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\Tree
[.2
    [.2-1 ]
    [.2-2 ]
]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]