# How to reflect duplicating a tree horizontally?

Tags: tikz-qtree

I'm following the solution from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35535/14757) to construct a tree using `tikz-qtree`. It's working very well as you can see on the image below.

[image]

The tree is to show the matches of a championship.

But I'd like to **reflect (duplicating)** the tree to show the other matches, that is, to go up from `champion` to the `Finalist 2` and so on.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.Champion 
        [.{Finalist 1}
            [.{Semi Finalist 1} 
               [.{kk}
                 [. kk ]
                 [. kk ]  ]
               [.{kk} 
                 [. kk ]
                 [. kk ] ] ]
            [.{Semi finalist 2} 
                           [.{kk}
                             [. kk ]
                             [. kk ]  ]
                           [.{kk} 
                             [. kk ]
                             [. kk ] ] ]
                              ] 
]
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\tikzset{grow=up}` do anything (and/or `grow'`)?

Comment: I'm using `\tikzset{edge from parent fork down}`.

Comment: Well, then `edge from parent fork up`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, no. This changes the connectors. I want them like the figure and also going up, a kind of mixture of down and up.

Comment: Down and up? Huh. So, the nodes reflect the teams not the matches? You want the same tree mirrored to have a X-like figure?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, yes, exactly. I want the roots and the leaves of the tree.

Comment: The placement of `tikz-qtree`’s trees are a little *fishy* (see [How to position qtrees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106761) ). I’d propose a slightly different solution than Alan Munn’s but giving how `tikz-qtree` does (not) work, his may be the easiest solution in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this more or less how  Qrrbrbirlbel  suggests (unless I've misunderstood what you want.)

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\tikzset{font=\small,
edge from parent fork down,
level distance=1.75cm,
every node/.style=
    {top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt
    },
edge from parent/.style=
    {draw=blue!50,
    thick
    }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[edge from parent fork up,grow'=up]
\Tree [
        [.{Finalist 1}
            [.{Semi Finalist 1} 
               [.{kk}
                 [. kk ]
                 [. kk ]  ]
               [.{kk} 
                 [. kk ]
                 [. kk ] ] ]
            [.{Semi finalist 2} 
                           [.{kk}
                             [. kk ]
                             [. kk ]  ]
                           [.{kk} 
                             [. kk ]
                             [. kk ] ] ]
                              ] 
]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\Tree [.Champion
        [.{Finalist 1}
            [.{Semi Finalist 1} 
               [.{kk}
                 [. kk ]
                 [. kk ]  ]
               [.{kk} 
                 [. kk ]
                 [. kk ] ] ]
            [.{Semi finalist 2} 
                           [.{kk}
                             [. kk ]
                             [. kk ]  ]
                           [.{kk} 
                             [. kk ]
                             [. kk ] ] ]
                              ] 
]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: More or less. I would like to identify both `champion` nodes. It's strange to show that node two times.

Comment: So you mean you want to have a single champion node shared by both? Then just remove the `yshift` parameter from the second scope.

Comment: OK, it works. But in fact, it prints the node two times but overlapping so that the visual is what I want. Try to change the text of those two nodes, with different sizes. Then we can see both nodes. Every time when I change the champion team I'll need to change in two places. Maybe a command to its name is a good option.

Comment: I removed the duplicate node.  The top tree now has no label.

Answer (score 5):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees,positioning}

\tikzset{
    font=\small,
    level distance=1.75cm,
    every node/.style={
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!25,
        rectangle,rounded corners,
        minimum height=8mm,
        draw=blue!75,
        very thick,
        drop shadow,
        align=center,
        text depth = 0pt
    },
    edge from parent/.style={
        draw=blue!50,
        thick
    }
}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    link tree/.style args={#1of#2}{% not so sure about this ...
        every tree node/.append style={#1=\the\tikzleveldistance of #2\if\relax\detokenize{\tikz@growth@anchor}\relax\else.\tikz@growth@anchor\fi,anchor=center}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[every tree node/.try] (champ) {Champion};
\begin{scope}[link tree=above of champ, grow=up,edge from parent fork up]
\Tree [.\node (fin2) {Finalist 2};
        [.{Semi Finalist 3} 
           [.{kk}
             [. kk ]
             [. kk ]  ]
           [.{kk} 
             [. kk ]
             [. kk ] ] ]
        [.{Semi finalist 4} 
                       [.{kk}
                         [. kk ]
                         [. kk ]  ]
                       [.{kk} 
                         [. kk ]
                         [. kk ] ] ]
        ]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[link tree=below of champ, grow=down, edge from parent fork down]
\Tree
        [.\node (fin1) {Finalist 1};
            [.{Semi Finalist 1} 
               [.{kk}
                 [. kk ]
                 [. kk ]  ]
               [.{kk} 
                 [. kk ]
                 [. kk ] ] ]
            [.{Semi finalist 2} 
                           [.{kk}
                             [. kk ]
                             [. kk ]  ]
                           [.{kk} 
                             [. kk ]
                             [. kk ] ] ]
                              ] 
\end{scope}
\path[edge from parent] (champ) edge (fin2) edge (fin1);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]