# Drawing recursive randomized structures with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

After I learned earlier today how to draw nice randomized trees ([Draw randomized tree in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128559/draw-randomized-tree-in-tikz/128566?noredirect=1#128566)) , I discovered that I'm not quite satisfied with how the results look like - because the structure I want to draw is not really a tree, but actually a shower of high energy particles. Here's the best I can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\define@key{hepshower}{nTracks}{\edef\nTracks{#1}}
\define@key{hepshower}{phimin}{\edef\phiMin{#1}}
\define@key{hepshower}{phisep}{\edef\phiSep{#1}}
\define@key{hepshower}{phimax}{\edef\phiMax{#1}}
\define@key{hepshower}{rmin}{\edef\radMin{#1}}
\define@key{hepshower}{rmax}{\edef\radMax{#1}}
\define@key{hepshower}{br}{\edef\branchingProbability{#1}}
\define@key{hepshower}{maxdepth}{\edef\maxDepth{#1}}
\presetkeys{hepshower}{nTracks=5,phimin=-90,phimax=90,rmin=0.5,rmax=1.0,phisep=10,br=0.9,maxdepth=3}{}

\newcommand\drawshower[2][]{
  \typeout{#2}
  \setkeys{hepshower}{#1}{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\nTracks} {
      \pgfmathparse{(\radMax-\radMin)*rnd+\radMin}
      \edef\radVal{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathparse{\phiMin+(\phiMax-\phiMin)*(\i-1)/\nTracks + rnd * ((\phiMax-\phiMin)/\nTracks-\phiSep) + \phiSep/2}
      \edef\phiVal{\pgfmathresult}
      \typeout{#2 \i : \phiVal - \radVal}
      \edef\coordname{#2-showerchild\i}
      \coordinate (\coordname) at (\phiVal:\radVal);
      \draw[black] (#2) --  (\coordname);
      \pgfmathparse{(\radMax-\radMin)*rnd+\radMin}
      \pgfmathparse{rnd}
      \ifnumcomp{\maxDepth}{>}{0}{
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\pgfmathresult pt<\branchingProbability pt}}{
          \drawshower[#1,maxdepth=\maxDepth-1]{\coordname}
        }{}
      }{}
    }
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (test);
  \drawshower[phimin=0,phimax=180]{test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you run the output, you see from the `\typeout`s that all the nodes are created and everything seems to work - apart from the fact that only the first iteration seems to be drawn. I think this has something to do with the polar coordinates, but I can't quite figure out what's wrong with it.

---

### Edit

Follwing a comment from Qrrbibel, here is an image of a shower that looks like what I was hoping for:

[image: Atmospheric Collision]

As you can see, it has a tree-like structure, but the nodes from different branches are not leveled and the lines are decreasing in length and varying in angle as the tree expands, giving the whole thing a somewhat more realistic look as compared to purely schematic trees.

Comment: Can you add an example or a link to “a shower of high energy particles”. How does that look like? Why are you using `xkeyval`? TikZ already uses the `pgfkeys` package and that integrates nicely. By the way, in your code, you use `\pgfmathparse` twice successively, the result from the first one is lost and never accessed.